# EF Core - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm having an issue where EF Core does not allow me to add my second migration.
I have the following DataContext setup :

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, IdentityUserClaim<Guid>, UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<Guid>, IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>, IdentityUserToken<Guid>>
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    /* Global */
    public virtual DbSet<Audit> Audits { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AuditType> AuditType { get; set; }

    /* Portal */
    public virtual DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GroupType> GroupTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GroupProperty> GroupProperties { get; set; }


    /* SVault */
    public virtual DbSet<LicensePropertyType> LicensePropertyTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LicenseProduct> LicenseProducts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LicenseState> LicenseStates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LicenseType> LicenseTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LicenseStatus> LicenseStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BackupState> BackupStates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BackupMode> BackupModes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        IList<AuditType> audittypes = new List<AuditType>()
        {
            new AuditType() { Id = 1, Name = "USER_CREATE" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 2, Name = "USER_UPDATE" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 3, Name = "USER_DELETE" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 4, Name = "USER_RESET_PASSWORD" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 5, Name = "USER_2FA_GENERATE" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 6, Name = "USER_TOKEN_GENERATE" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 7, Name = "USER_REQUEST_RESET_PASSWORD" },

            new AuditType() { Id = 20, Name = "ROLE_ADD" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 21, Name = "ROLE_DELETE" },

            new AuditType() { Id = 30, Name = "GROUP_CREATE" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 31, Name = "GROUP_UPDATE" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 32, Name = "GROUP_DELETE" },

            new AuditType() { Id = 35, Name = "GROUP_PROPERTY_ADD" },
            new AuditType() { Id = 36, Name = "GROUP_PROPERTY_DELETE" },

            new AuditType() { Id = 50, Name = "SVAULT_LICENSE_CREATE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 51, Name = "SVAULT_LICENSE_UPDATE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 52, Name = "SVAULT_LICENSE_DELETE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 53, Name = "SVAULT_LICENSE_VALIDATE_TRIAL", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 54, Name = "SVAULT_LICENSE_MIGRATE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 55, Name = "SVAULT_LICENSE_PROPERTIES_UPDATE", ProductId = 1 },

            new AuditType() { Id = 70, Name = "SVAULT_DATASET_CREATE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 71, Name = "SVAULT_DATASET_UPDATE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 72, Name = "SVAULT_DATASET_DELETE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 73, Name = "SVAULT_DATASET_RESTORE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 74, Name = "SVAULT_DATASET_BACKUP", ProductId = 1 },

            new AuditType() { Id = 80, Name = "SVAULT_DATASET_SCHED_CREATE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 81, Name = "SVAULT_DATASET_SCHED_UPDATE", ProductId = 1 },
            new AuditType() { Id = 82, Name = "SVAULT_DATASET_SCHED_DELETE", ProductId = 1 },
        };

        Guid mProvider = Guid.NewGuid();

        IList<User> users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "*****************", NormalizedUserName = "*****************".ToUpper(), Email = "*****************", NormalizedEmail = "*****************".ToUpper(), EmailConfirmed = true, PasswordHash = "*****************", SecurityStamp = "*****************", ConcurrencyStamp = "*****************", PhoneNumber = null, PhoneNumberConfirmed = false, TwoFactorEnabled = false, LockoutEnd = null, LockoutEnabled = true, AccessFailedCount = 0, FirstName = "*****************", LastName = "*****************", IsAdmin = true, GroupId = mProvider },
                    new User() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "*****************", NormalizedUserName = "*****************".ToUpper(), Email = "*****************", NormalizedEmail = "*****************".ToUpper(), EmailConfirmed = true, PasswordHash = "*****************", SecurityStamp = "*****************", ConcurrencyStamp = "*****************", PhoneNumber = null, PhoneNumberConfirmed = false, TwoFactorEnabled = false, LockoutEnd = null, LockoutEnabled = true, AccessFailedCount = 0, FirstName = "*****************", LastName = "*****************", IsAdmin = true, GroupId = mProvider }
        };

        IList<Product> products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product(){ Id = 1 ,LongName = "AGS Backup SVault", Description = String.Empty, ShortName = "SVault", RouteUrl = "/svault/dashboard", IconUrl = "assets/images/picto/picto_backup.svg", ThemeColor = "ags-500", Enabled = true },
            new Product(){ Id = 2 ,LongName = "AGS Hosting", Description = String.Empty, ShortName = "Hosting", RouteUrl = "/hosting/dashboard", IconUrl = "assets/images/picto/picto_hosting.svg", ThemeColor = "ags-600", Enabled = false },
            new Product(){ Id = 3 ,LongName = "AGS VEEAM Cloud Connect", Description = String.Empty, ShortName = "VEEAM", RouteUrl = "/veeam/dashboard", IconUrl = "assets/images/picto/picto_veeam.svg", ThemeColor = "ags-300", Enabled = false },
            new Product(){ Id = 4 ,LongName = "AGS Mail Zimbra", Description = String.Empty, ShortName = "Zimbra", RouteUrl = "/mail/dashboard", IconUrl = "assets/images/picto/picto_messagerie.svg", ThemeColor = "ags-700", Enabled = false },
            new Product(){ Id = 5 ,LongName = "AGS Mail Exchange", Description = String.Empty, ShortName = "Exchange", RouteUrl = "/mail/dashboard", IconUrl = "assets/images/picto/picto_messagerie.svg", ThemeColor = "ags-700", Enabled = false },
            new Product(){ Id = 6 ,LongName = "AGS Office365", Description = String.Empty, ShortName = "Office365", RouteUrl = "/office365/dashboard", IconUrl = "assets/images/picto/picto_office.svg", ThemeColor = "ags-800", Enabled = false },
            new Product(){ Id = 7 ,LongName = "AGS MailProtect", Description = String.Empty, ShortName = "MailProtect", RouteUrl = "/mailprotect/dashboard", IconUrl = "assets/images/picto/picto_protect.svg", ThemeColor = "ags-900", Enabled = false },
            new Product(){ Id = 8 ,LongName = "AGS MailInBlack", Description = String.Empty, ShortName = "MailInBlack", RouteUrl = "/mailinblack/dashboard", IconUrl = "assets/images/picto/picto_protect.svg", ThemeColor = "ags-900", Enabled = false },
            new Product(){ Id = 9 ,LongName = "AGS MonCloud", Description = String.Empty, ShortName = "MonCloud", RouteUrl = "/moncloud/dashboard", IconUrl = "assets/images/picto/picto_moncloud.svg", ThemeColor = "ags-400", Enabled = false }
        };
        IList<Role> roles = new List<Role>()
        {
            /* SVault Roles */
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 1, Name = RolesHelper.SvaultRoles.RoleAdmin, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.SvaultRoles.RoleAdmin.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 1, Name = RolesHelper.SvaultRoles.RoleBackup, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.SvaultRoles.RoleBackup.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 1, Name = RolesHelper.SvaultRoles.RoleRestore, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.SvaultRoles.RoleRestore.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 1, Name = RolesHelper.SvaultRoles.RoleRead, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.SvaultRoles.RoleRead.ToUpper() },

            /* Hosting Roles */
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 2, Name = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleAdmin, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleAdmin.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 2, Name = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleCreate, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleCreate.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 2, Name = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleDelete, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleDelete.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 2, Name = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleEdit, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleEdit.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 2, Name = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleRead, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.HostingRoles.RoleRead.ToUpper() },

            /* VEEAM Roles */
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 3, Name = RolesHelper.VEEAMRoles.RoleAdmin, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.VEEAMRoles.RoleAdmin.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 3, Name = RolesHelper.VEEAMRoles.RoleBackup, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.VEEAMRoles.RoleBackup.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 3, Name = RolesHelper.VEEAMRoles.RoleRestore, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.VEEAMRoles.RoleRestore.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 3, Name = RolesHelper.VEEAMRoles.RoleRead, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.VEEAMRoles.RoleRead.ToUpper() },

            /* Mail Roles */
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 4, Name = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleAdmin, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleAdmin.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 4, Name = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleCreate, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleCreate.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 4, Name = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleDelete, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleDelete.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 4, Name = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleEdit, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleEdit.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 4, Name = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleRead, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailRoles.RoleRead.ToUpper() },

            /* Mail Office */
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 5, Name = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleAdmin, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleAdmin.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 5, Name = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleCreate, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleCreate.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 5, Name = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleDelete, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleDelete.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 5, Name = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleEdit, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleEdit.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 5, Name = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleRead, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.Office365Roles.RoleRead.ToUpper() },

            /* MailProtect Roles */
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 6, Name = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleAdmin, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleAdmin.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 6, Name = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleCreate, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleCreate.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 6, Name = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleDelete, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleDelete.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 6, Name = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleEdit, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleEdit.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 6, Name = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleRead, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MailProtectRoles.RoleRead.ToUpper() },

            /* MonCloud Roles */
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 7, Name = RolesHelper.MonCloudRoles.RoleAdmin, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MonCloudRoles.RoleAdmin.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 7, Name = RolesHelper.MonCloudRoles.RoleSync, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MonCloudRoles.RoleSync.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 7, Name = RolesHelper.MonCloudRoles.RoleRestore, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MonCloudRoles.RoleRestore.ToUpper() },
            new Role() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 7, Name = RolesHelper.MonCloudRoles.RoleRead, NormalizedName = RolesHelper.MonCloudRoles.RoleRead.ToUpper() },
            };

            IList<GroupType> grouptypes = new List<GroupType>()
            {
                new GroupType() { Id = 1, Name = "Cloud Provider", PictoName = "cloud" },
                new GroupType() { Id = 2, Name = "Partenaire", PictoName = "supervisor_account" },
                new GroupType() { Id = 3, Name = "Client", PictoName = "group" },
                new GroupType() { Id = 4, Name = "Groupe", PictoName = "folder" }
            };

            IList<Group> groups = new List<Group>()
            {
                new Group() { Id = mProvider, Name = "AGS Cloud", GroupTypeId = 1, ParentGroupId = null },
            };

            IList<GroupProperty> groupProperties = new List<GroupProperty>()
            {
                new GroupProperty() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = 1, GroupId = mProvider, Name = Domain.Portal.GroupProperties.community_id.ToString(), Value = Guid.Empty.ToString() }
            };

            IList<LicenseType> licenseTypes = new List<LicenseType>()
            {
                new LicenseType() { Id = 1, Name = "Cloud", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 1 },
                new LicenseType() { Id = 2, Name = "Hybrid Mirroir", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 2 },
                new LicenseType() { Id = 4, Name = "Hybrid Illimitée", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 3 },
                new LicenseType() { Id = 8, Name = "Locale", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 4 }
            };

            IList<LicenseStatus> licenseStatus = new List<LicenseStatus>()
            {
                new LicenseStatus() { Id = -1, Name = "NotInstalled", IconName = "highlight_off", IconColor = "grey-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 3 },
                new LicenseStatus() { Id = 0, Name = "Online", IconName = "wifi", IconColor = "green-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 1 },
                new LicenseStatus() { Id = 1, Name = "Disabled", IconName = "delete", IconColor = "red-600-fg", IsFilterable = false },
                new LicenseStatus() { Id = 2, Name = "MarkForDelete", IconName = "delete_forever", IconColor = "red-600-fg", IsFilterable = false },
                new LicenseStatus() { Id = 4, Name = "Detached", IconName = "indeterminate_check_box", IconColor = "red-600-fg", IsFilterable = false },
                new LicenseStatus() { Id = 8, Name = "Offline", IconName = "wifi_off", IconColor = "red-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 2 }
            };

            IList<LicenseState> licenseStates = new List<LicenseState>()
            {
                new LicenseState() { Id = 0, Name = "NotInstalled", IconName = "highlight_off", IconColor = "grey-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 9 },
                new LicenseState() { Id = 1, Name = "NotConfigured", IconName = "perm_data_setting", IconColor = "grey-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 8 },
                new LicenseState() { Id = 2, Name = "Failed", IconName = "sms_failed", IconColor = "red-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 7 },
                new LicenseState() { Id = 3, Name = "NotConnected", IconName = "wifi_off", IconColor = "red-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 6 },
                new LicenseState() { Id = 4, Name = "Suspended", IconName = "pause", IconColor = "orange-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 5 },
                new LicenseState() { Id = 5, Name = "Killed", IconName = "stop", IconColor = "orange-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 4 },
                new LicenseState() { Id = 6, Name = "Maintenance", IconName = "outlined_flag", IconColor = "blue-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 3 },
                new LicenseState() { Id = 7, Name = "Running", IconName = "play_circle_outline", IconColor = "yellow-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 2 },
                new LicenseState() { Id = 8, Name = "Completed", IconName = "check", IconColor = "green-600-fg", IsFilterable = true, OrderBy = 1 }
            };

            IList<BackupMode> backupmodes = new List<BackupMode>()
            {
                new BackupMode() { Id = 1, Name = "Cloud", IconName = "cloud", IconColor = "blue-600-fg" },
                new BackupMode() { Id = 2, Name = "Locale", IconName = "dns", IconColor = "grey-600-fg" },
                new BackupMode() { Id = 4, Name = "Cloud & Locale", IconName = "all_inclusive", IconColor = "light-blue-300-fg" }
            };

            /* Code to allow 0 value in BackupState -> Id */
            modelBuilder.Entity<LicenseState>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            modelBuilder.Entity<BackupState>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            modelBuilder.Entity<LicenseStatus>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            /* End */

            modelBuilder.Entity<GroupType>().HasData(grouptypes);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasData(groups);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasData(products);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasData(roles);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(users);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LicenseType>().HasData(licenseTypes);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LicenseStatus>().HasData(licenseStatus);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LicenseState>().HasData(licenseStates);
            modelBuilder.Entity<BackupMode>().HasData(backupmodes);
            modelBuilder.Entity<GroupProperty>().HasData(groupProperties);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AuditType>().HasData(audittypes);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            /* Has to be set up after base.OnModelCreating */
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(userRole =>
            {
                userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

                userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                    .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                    .IsRequired();

                userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                    .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<GroupProperty>().HasIndex(b => b.Name);
            modelBuilder.Entity<GroupProperty>().HasIndex(b => b.Value);

            /*modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasOne(b => b.ParentGroup)
                .WithMany(b => b.ChildGroupsHidden)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.ParentGroupId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);*/
        }
    }
```

So when I initially created my first Migration, I used the following:

`Add-Migration "Initialization" -o "Data\Migrations"`

But every time I try to add a second migration, when I'd like to add new field(s) to a table, I get this error saying that `Value cannot be null (Parameter: Key)`

```
    public class Audit
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey(nameof(GroupId))]
            public Group Group { get; set; }
            public Guid UserId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
            public User User { get; set; }
            public int AuditTypeId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey(nameof(AuditTypeId))]
            public AuditType AuditType { get; set; }
            public string IP { get; set; }
            public string BrowserInfo { get; set; }
            public string OriginalObject { get; set; }
            public string UpdatedObject { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
            **public string TestField { get; set; }**
        }
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why I'm not able to add that second migration?
The error shown is :

```bsh
    PM> Add-Migration "Test_Audit"
    Build started...
    Build succeeded.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
          Entity Framework Core 3.1.2 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
          Executed DbCommand (13ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          SELECT 1
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
          Executed DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
          Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          SELECT 1
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
          Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
          Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
          FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
          ORDER BY [MigrationId];
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
          No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
          Entity Framework Core 3.1.2 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityReferenceMap.TryGet(Object entity, IEntityType entityType, InternalEntityEntry& entry, Boolean throwOnNonUniqueness)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.TryGetEntry(Object entity, IEntityType entityType, Boolean throwOnTypeMismatch)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.KeyPropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, IReadOnlyList`1 containingPrincipalKeys, IReadOnlyList`1 containingForeignKeys, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.KeyPropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, IReadOnlyList`1 keys, IReadOnlyList`1 foreignKeys, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectKeyChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase propertyBase, Boolean setModified)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase property, Boolean setModified)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetProperty(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value, Boolean isMaterialization, Boolean setModified, Boolean isCascadeDelete, CurrentValueType valueType)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetProperty(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value, Boolean isMaterialization, Boolean setModified, Boolean isCascadeDelete)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.CascadeDelete(InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean force, IEnumerable`1 foreignKeys)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.UpdateAdapter.CascadeDelete(IUpdateEntry entry, IEnumerable`1 foreignKeys)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDataOperations(DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IModel source, IModel target)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
    Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
```

My understanding is that somehow we have a Key field which is initialized to null, so it is not able to create the new migration, but I'm not able to find where that problem comes from. The odd part is that the first migration works correctly.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you guys!

Comment: Did you run an "update database" after the migration?

Comment: The error comes when I try to add the migration, not update the database according to the new migration. In fact, if I clean the entire Migrations folder, then run Add-Migration "Initialization" -o "Data\Migrations" it works. But as soon as I try to add a second migration with small changes inside a class, this error pops out :(

Comment: Yes, but did you ever apply your migration? That's what you need to do before you make a new migration. Otherwise you're trying to make a migration, on a migration, which doesn't  make sense, so naturally it fails.

Comment: @CoderLee, Yes the initial migration has been applied to the database :)

Comment: So you have run the Update-Database command then?

Comment: @CoderLee Yes, process is : Add-Migration "Initialization" -o "Data\Migrations" then Update-Database, then I change one field in a class as stated above, then I run Add-Migration "Adding field to a table" which causes the error to be thrown

Comment: Is it just the Audit model that won't work when changed, have you tried leaving Audit alone and updating another one?

Comment: Yes, any classes where I try to change a field generates that issue. I'm running tests for couple of hours now, I found that commenting all the seeding makes all migrations works. But I'm not able to understand why...

Comment: I think it's the seed data, sounds like it's trying to re-seed on your migration which causes the break. I updated my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit from comments*

"...we have to use fixed Guids or fixed Ids. Otherwise, any subsequent migrations will generate that new Guid/Id using the Guid.NewGuid() and try to seed that new data, unfortunately as we have already linked those Ids with some Foreign Key, EF is not able to proceed."

---

After you make your initial (or any) migration, be sure to run the `Update-Database` command to apply your migration. After it's been applied fromthe update you can then make a new migration, update, and repeat as needed in youre application development.

*for example:*

Make changes to ef models, code, etc then run add migration command:

```bsh
Add-Migration NewMigrationAfterChanges
```

Apply the migration with the update db command:

```bsh
Update-Database
```

Now you can make changes and add a new migration, assuming it updated without an error or something unexpected occurred. See [MSDN on EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs#create-a-migration) for more details on using EF core.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, but I'm not in the case you describe, I do run Update-Database properly after first Migration created, problem occurs on other Migration created afterall :(

Comment: No problem, please see the updates. Hopefully that'll help make a difference now

Comment: In order to make it a bit more clear, the only line that causes my issue right now is :
`modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(users);`

Comment: Oh ok, where is your User's DbSet then? Looks like it isn't there which would cause EF to not be able to find it, hence the null key. Pretty sure EF needs the DbSet for modelBuilder to work, so try adding that in.

Comment: In my DataContext class declaration, I do inherit from other class in order to specify and customize the Identity table using Guid instead of int (User / Role / Claim) as shown below
`public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, IdentityUserClaim<Guid>, UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<Guid>, IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>, IdentityUserToken<Guid>>`

Comment: We still need to declare the DbSet<TEntity> for the Models though. Otherwise, why would we need to declare any of them? Check out the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=efcore-3.1) for specifics.

Comment: I gave it a try and added the DbSet<User> and DbSet<Role>, we have same issue :(

Comment: Even after clearing everything out? Like removing the previous migrations, and starting fresh

Comment: Then you should submit a ticket to the [EF core](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues) team with all the details, because you found an edge case it seems. Remove your seed logic and just use a script for seeding. That way you can continue using EF core.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, most of the objects I seed like User / Role will use Guid.NewGuid(), but every time I add a new Migration a new Guid is generated, which causes HasData to try delete all and recreate. There has to be some Foreign Key which restrict deletion. I'm writing code to fix all those Guids and will report back. Thanks a lot !

Comment: That's good, have you looked at this [seeding ef core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)? Might be because you haven't specified the foreign key like MS shows, maybe adding those in the User list will fix it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok I found the issue, as I stated, we have to use fixed Guids or fixed Ids. Otherwise, any subsequent migrations will generate that new Guid/Id using the Guid.NewGuid() and try to seed that new data, unfortunately as we have already linked those Ids with some Foreign Key, EF is not able to proceed. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you try adding in the foreign key already? I'm curious if that makes a difference

Comment: Nope it does not :)

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of research and help of @CoderLee, I figured out that we should not use Guid.NewGuid() while seeding data, this will cause subsequent Migrations to try seeding data again and again based on Guids that are already used by some Foreign Key.